# Entity Framework with value types replacing primitives

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-5

Working on code (C#9 .NET5) that has a lot of this (example code)

```
void Enroll(string id, string id2)
```

After refactoring and adding value types, the code looks like this

```
void Enroll(StudentId id, SchoolId id2)

public class StudentId{
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

This solved a lot of issues, including some bugs . However, I am having issues with Entity Framework. I create ValueConverters and register them such as this

```
ValueConverter conv = new ValueConverter<StudentId, string>(
            v => v.studentId,
            v => new StudentId(v)
        );

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(c => c.ID)
                .HasConversion(conv);
```

There are issues both with Linq filtering when

```
return await context.students.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(e => e.StudentId.Equals(studenId))
                .ToListAsync();
```

As EF cannot create a query based on my Equals method, which I understand my I cannot find a sensible workaround (doing ToList() etc before filtering is not a solution). I get these kind of messages

```
This commonly occurs when the specified member is unmapped. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Also, when trying to create a migration, after some modifications based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors), EF wants to create a table for StudentId and SchoolId, which is not what I need. I just need to translate StudentId back and forth. Database tables should remain unchanged.

I feel like this should be easy to handle, and that I am on the wrong path. How should I approach EF with my code changes here?

Comment: There are no "value types" in EF Core while in .NET value types are structs, while the types you posted are reference types. EF Core knows how to map LINQ queries involving primitive types but has no idea what to do with the complex objects you used. As the error says, EF sees an object with no mapping information. `value` has no specific meaning, it's just a property with the name `value`.

Comment: Were you trying to implement a [DDD value object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/implement-value-objects) instead? You can use owned types for this.

Comment: Well, it is a value object as two StudentId objects with same value are equal. This is purely a code change. No DB changes needed. If no ORM were used, this would be simple as I would just map StudentId.value in the query, so I need an analogue solution. I need EF to understand that StudentId should map to a "id (varchar)" on Student table.

Comment: Perhaps use an Owned Type instead of a Value Converter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities, and write `e.StudentId.Value == studenId.Value`